# JavaScript generating an upload component for Vugen

Tags: javascript, client, correlation, loadrunner

Using Vugen, working on a application that generates a component to upload files on client-side, component doesn't appear during runtime as it is generated by JavaScript functions on the client side.

I have two issues:

1. I have the functions that generate the browse field. How do I use it in my script?
2. I have also created a javascipt based script in Vugen as well. Facing issues with correlation using `web.create_html_param`, as it doesn't capture anything.

**Note**: If possible, please let me know how to convert javascript function to loadrunner C function. The function cant be used as-is in the script.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Have you seen my blog post about this topic here?: http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/HP-LoadRunner-and-Performance/How-to-use-JavaScript-in-your-HP-LoadRunner-scripts/ba-p/6197321#.U_mEx_mSyk4

Comment: Hi @cracker, thanks for the post! Does it work for LoadRunner11.04 as well? I'll follow the steps if it does.